# Nested Attributes form. How to narrow down the contents of fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have something similar to these:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weeks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tests, through: :weeks

  accepts_nested_attribues_for :weeks, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attribues_for :tests, allow_destroy: true
end

class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :tests, dependent: :destroy
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :week
end
```

Note: these Models aren't real, they are an oversimplified equivalent of what I have.

And I have something like this on the view (haml):

```
=form_for @event do |e|
  %h3 Event
  =render 'form', e: e # This partial contains the general data of the Event.

  %h3 Weeks

  %table
    %thead
      %th Start
      %th End
      %th X
    %tbody
      =e.fields_for :weeks do |w|
        =render 'week_fields', w: w
  =link_to_add_fields 'Add Week', e, :weeks # Custom helper that adds the fields of the week to the end of the table via JavaScript.

  %h3 Tests

  %table
    %thead
      %th Field 1
      %th Field 2
      %th Field 3
      %th X
    %tbody
      =e.fields_for :tests do |t|
        =render 'test_fields', t: t
  =link_to_add_fields 'Add Test', e, :tests
```

This would work straightout, except the last part (where I add the data for each Test) wouldn't allow me to specify to which Week the Test belongs to (unless I added something like a select box). So, to alleviate that, I changed it to something like this:

```
  %h3 Tests

  -@weeks.each do |week|
    %h5=week.start # Prints the 'start' of the Week.
    %table
      %thead
        %th Field 1
        %th Field 2
        %th Field 3
        %th X
      %tbody
        =e.fields_for :tests do |t|
          =render 'test_fields', t: t, w: week.id
    =link_to_add_fields 'Add Test', e, :tests, parent: week.id
```

This would show a different table for each of the Weeks, but since I'm not narrowing down the `fields_for` scope, it is showing all the Tests on each Week block instead of including only the Test of that individual Week.

Is there a way to make this `field_for` to only show the records for the selected Week? I'm already doing a `.each` loop, could I use that value to narrow down what `fields_for` is showing?

Btw, notice that I'm sending `week.id` on both the render and my custom helper. This is so that the fields generated by both of these to include the `week_id` value once the form is submitted. Theoretically the value shouldn't be needed for `render`, but since both are using the same partial, I opted for including the value on both, so as to not do extra validation on the partial when it's not coming from the helper.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest changing your associations: event has many weeks, week has many tests and event has many tests through weeks. Then your what you want to do is very easy.

Comment: How would that be? I'm using `has_many through` cause that'd allow me to edit the value of Tests in the same form. Are you suggesting I remove that? EDIT: Woops, didn't see you mentioned `through` as well. I'm not too sure what you're suggesting I change.

Comment: Ah, you have it already. In that case you should be able to do: `e.fields_for :tests, week.tests do |t|`

Comment: That did it! YAY! You should reply that as the answer, so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fields_for` accepts an optional second argument to specify model(s) for which you want to build the fields. If it is empty, rails will use specified association name to fetch the records. In your case, this will do the trick:

```
= e.fields_for :tests, week.tests do |t|
```